# Bootstrap img Opacity

Tags: html, css

Regarding the CSS `background-image` attribute or an `<img />` tag, is there a bootstrap class that can change the opacity of the image.

I want to put text over it that is not opaque. I found the `opacity-#` class, but it doesn't seem to work for image DOM tags or the CSS `background-image` attribute.

My feeling is I just have to write the styling myself, but I was hoping to avoid that...

Comment: I fear you may have to add that yourself. Even the examples I can find (like https://bootstrapcreative.com/pattern/jumbotron-background-image-opacity-bootstrap-4) add custom CSS for this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That's disappointing. Maybe there's a more robust library I can use?

Comment: Just to note that you can't alter the opacity of a background on an element without altering the opacity of the contents of the element which you probably don't want. You can use a pseudo element to put the background image in and alter the opacity of that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure if there is a way to play with the opacity using boostrap

Normally I change the  opacity with CSS like this:

```
img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The opacity property can take a value from 0.0 - 1.0. The lower value, the more transparent

For bootstrap I only found this:
Here is some examples using bootstrap for opacity

```
<div class="opacity-100">...</div>
<div class="opacity-75">...</div>
<div class="opacity-50">...</div>
<div class="opacity-25">...</div>
```

The opacity level describes the transparency level, where 1 is not transparent at all, .5 is 50% visible, and 0 is completely transparent.

[Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/opacity/)

[CSS IMG opacity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)